# Как JOIN две таблицы SQL если один из столбцов текстовый и содержит лишние данные?

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы, которые необходимо JOIN. Проблема в том, что в первой таблице нужный столбец "id" в int64, а во второй таблице в виде текста с префиксом ("abc123", "abc456" - где цифры это id). Конвертировать "id" первой таблицы в текст и дописать к нему префикс, или обрезать префикс столбца второй таблицы и конвертировать в число - не получается.

```
Ошибка - JOIN: each equality predicate argument must depend on exactly one JOIN input
```

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: `JOIN .. ON table2.text LIKE CONCAT('%', CAST(table1.int64 AS CHAR))`. Ну а конкретный оптимальный синтаксис зависит от ответов на вопросы выше.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вынести преобразование в подзапрос(где вы сначала сформируете нужное поле), а не делать его прямо в соединении, например:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table2 t2
  JOIN (SELECT CONCAT('%', CAST(table1.int64 AS CHAR)) AS field1
        FROM table1 t1)f1
    ON t2.table2.text LIKE f1.field1
```